# Chainlink Fullfill_alarm() not calling back after successfull request send to oracle on testing with mocha

Tags: oracle, mocha.js, ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I'm trying to test the Chainlink alarm oracle following the documentation steps with hardhat on a kovan fork network.

[https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-alarm-clock/#:~:text=ala](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-alarm-clock/#:%7E:text=ala)

When I test the contract with `npx hardhat test` it looks like it hits the request function to the oracle but never calling back the fulfill_alarm().

I wonder if that might be an issue with the fork network or with my testing code.

I'm using Alchemy api as url for the fork network on kovan.

Also, I'm using a timeout with mocha so it can wait for the callback to execute, but never hits.

The first it statement executes correctly, but then on the second one which is suposed to increment lotteryId + 1 once the lottery is done (fulfill_alarm() called) doesn't pass. It looks like the function never gets executed by the chainlink oracle.

oracle: `0xAA1DC356dc4B18f30C347798FD5379F3D77ABC5b`

jobId: `'982105d690504c5d9ce374d040c08654'`

Solidity code:

```
    //Starting Oracle Alarm
  function start_new_lottery(uint256 duration) public {
      require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED, "can't start a n
      lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
      Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, add
      req.addUint("until", block.timestamp + duration);
      sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, req, oraclePayment);
       console.log('LINK REQ SEND');
   }

     //Callback Function after Oracle Alarm is Fulfilled
   function fulfill_alarm(bytes32 _requestId) public recordChainlinkFu
       require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN, "The lottery hasn'
       lotteryId = lotteryId + 1;
       console.log('ALARM_FULFILLED');
       pickWinner();
  }
```

test code:

```
const {expect} = require("chai");
```

const { time } = require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers");

describe("Lottery Contract", function() {

```
   //Defining global variables for testing.
   const price_lottery = ethers.BigNumber.from(1);
   let owner;
   let Lottery;
   let lottery;

  before(async function () {
      Lottery = await ethers.getContractFactory("Lottery");
      [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
      lottery = await Lottery.deploy(
          price_lottery,
      );

      //Starting new Lottery
      await lottery.start_new_lottery(60);

  });

   it("should start a chainlink alarm to init new lottery", async func

       let lottery_state = await lottery.lottery_state();

       expect(lottery_state).to.equal(0);

       //Initial value
       let lotteryId = await lottery.lotteryId();
      expect(lotteryId).to.equal(1);
  })

  it("increments lotteryID + 1, when chainlink alarm is fulfilled aft

      //Wait until alarm is fulfilled
      function timeout(ms) {
           return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
       }

       await timeout(120000);

       //Expected value
       let lotteryId = await lottery.lotteryId();
       expect(lotteryId).to.equal(2);
   })
```

})

Comment: Your code got cut off in width, some lines are not complete. Can you edit the post to include the full code?